# How to extract a highly linked node from a network

Tags: netlogo

I want to extract a node with highest degree centrality from the network. I don't want to extract a node with max links only. I want to extract the node along with the nodes adjacent to it.

Below is the code. In this code, I have loaded a network using nw extensions.

```
    extensions [nw]

    turtles-own [ explored? ]

    to setup
      ca
      crt 25
      ask turtles [fd random 15]
      load-graph
      extract_deg
    end


    to load-graph
      let filename user-file
      if (filename != false) [
        nw:load-graphml filename [
          set shape "circle"
          set size 1
        ]
        nw:set-context turtles links
      ]
    end


    to extract_deg
      let n turtles with [my-links = max [count link-neighbors] of turtles]
      ask n [show other turtles network:in-link-radius 1 turtles]
    end

    to layout
      ask turtles [ set size sqrt count my-links ]
      layout-spring turtles links 0.5 2 1 
      ask turtles [
      facexy 0 0
      fd (distancexy 0 0) / 100 ]
    end
```

Comment: Please ask multiple questions in separate questions so that StackOverflow is useful as a resource for other people looking for solutions as well. Also, what code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have edited the question and have added the code which I am trying in extract_deg to extract a node with the highest degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will choose one of the nodes with largest degree (just remove `one-of` if you want all of them), turn it red and make its network neighbours green.

You don't need the expression `[my-links = max [count link-neighbors] of turtles]`, standard NetLogo includes the very useful `with-max` primitive. However, I think your construction would have worked if you had counted my-links (like `let n turtles with [count my-links = max [count link-neighbors] of turtles]`). Then you have some syntax errors in the next line (the extension is `nw` and you don't need the `turtles`.

```
to extract_deg
  let maxk-set one-of turtles with-max [count my-links]
  ask maxk-set
  [ set color red
    ask other nw:turtles-in-radius 1 [set color green]
  ]
end
```